# Calling python script in node js => ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT

Tags: python, node.js

i node js project in which i call python script. The problem is that it displays only part of the output and the server drops with error ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT.

hello.py

```
import sys
for i in range(3000):
    print(i)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')


app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '10mb', extended: false }))

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    const spawn = require("child_process").spawn
    const pythonProcess = spawn('python', ["./hello.py"])
    pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        results = data.toString().split("\r\n")
        res.render("../index.ejs", {results})
    })
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000)
```

index.ejs

```
<h2>Results:</h2>
<% results.forEach(result => { %>
    <div><%= result %> </div>
<% }) %>
```

The result is page with numbers from 0 to 1550, each on separate line, but it should be 0 to 3000, what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens due to the fact that `data` is actually a **stream**, its output is read as chunks of data piece by piece, which means the listener `on('data',..` is being triggered more than once; every time a chunk is received.

To get the entire result we have to wait until all pieces are received, here is how:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const pythonProcess = spawn('python', ['./hello.py']);
  let result = [];

  // this listener will keep triggering until all chunks are received
  pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', data => {
    result = result.concat(data.toString().split('\r\n'));
  });
  // on.exit() will indicate that process has finished
  pythonProcess.on('exit', code => {
    console.log(`process has finished and exited with code: ${code}`);
    res.render('../index.ejs', { result });
  });
});
```

Hope I've helped